# Options menu doesn't accommodate icons

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu, nook

I tried adding an icon to a menu item on my rooted Nook Simple Touch (API 7).  The menu is only large enough to accommodate the text, so the icon is mostly off screen:

[image]

I thought the icon might simply be too large, so I tried 32x32 and 24x24 icons.  The menu remained the same size and the text was barely visible at the bottom.

Is there a way to make the menu larger?